# How to remove data usage from droid 2 welcome screen?

Tags: home-screen, motorola-droid-2

By mistake I checked data usage from android widgets, and now its in my droid 2 welcome screen. How can I remove it from the welcome screen?

Answer (score 3):

Press and hold (long press) on the widget, then drag it to the remove/trash icon that will appear.